# Decreased Hz Rate and Lag in Image Transfer with Multiple Subscriptions in ROS2 Communication

Tags: publisher, image-transport, subscribers

I'm encountering a problem in my ROS2 (Robot Operating System 2) communication setup where I've noticed a significant decrease in the frequency of data updates (measured in Hz) and increased lag in image transfer when multiple subscriptions are active.

Here's the scenario: I have multiple nodes subscribing to various topics, including topics for image transfer. However, as the number of subscriptions increases, I observe a drop in the update rate (Hz) for all subscribed topics, particularly noticeable in image transfer. This degradation in performance is causing significant delays and impacting the overall responsiveness of the system.

I've tried optimizing the code and ensuring efficient message handling, but the issue persists. I suspect that the problem might be related to how ROS2 handles multiple subscriptions concurrently or potentially due to resource limitations. However, I'm uncertain about the exact cause and how to mitigate it effectively.

Can someone provide insights or potential solutions to address this issue? Any guidance on optimizing ROS2 communication with multiple subscriptions, particularly in scenarios involving image transfer, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say that you have tried optimising the code and ensure efficient message handling - can you provide us with specific examples to show what you have tried and why it does not work? It would help others answer your question better if you add more supporting info specific to the problem - _e.g._ the stack trace (in formatted text) showing what the problem is, code samples that you have tried out, and the relevant config section if you've made some config changes

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Teja, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but if there is increased lag in image transfer when multiple subscriptions are active then you can try:
So there can be delay but you will not have code flow issue.

```
1)Maybe synchronisation/time sync
2)Use lifecycle node.
```

No delay need

```
3)If all image are published at same time,you can create a pointer for all of them i.e. create a array of images and publish.
```

Please check [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1242) also.